# How can i split a number that is inside a list?

Tags: python, list, split

like [198]
how can I split it to [1,9,8]?

plus I cant show my code that I did because I didn't do one am asking this out for my own benefit or knowledge.

Comment: Will the list only consist of one number?

Comment: If you're doing this for your own benefit or knowledge shouldn't you try it yourself first?

Comment: @talha israr  yes I want it to list each column in the list has only one number each like if the number is 30661 I want it to be [3,0,6,6,1]

Comment: @Encode.to.code i have given answer for multiple numbers but it also works for single num

Answer (score 2):

According to the comments in the question, each list has a single number on it. Here's a simple way to do the conversion, using [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
lst = [198]
[int(x) for x in str(lst[0])]
=> [1, 9, 8]
```

To extend my solution for lists with more elements (not a requirement in the question, but what the heck):

```
lst = [198, 199, 200]
[[int(x) for x in str(y)] for y in lst]
[[1, 9, 8], [1, 9, 9], [2, 0, 0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC for example you have list like `l=[198,128]`

```
l=[198,128]
[[int(y) for y in list(str(x))] for x in l]
Out[520]: [[1, 9, 8], [1, 2, 8]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. I kept it as easy as i could:

```
new=[]
test=[198]
for i in test:
    string=str(i)
    for j in string:
        new.append(int(j))
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

This will do the job:

```
>>> [int(x) for x in list(str([198][0]))]
[1, 9, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
list(map(int,str([198][0])))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try

```
toList=lambda Number: [int(val) for val in str(Number)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.It is working.
print(list(map(int,str([198][0]))))